# Creating a Google Cloud Task from a Firebase Function throws Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Task.payload_type is not set

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-tasks

I am trying to create a Task in a Google Cloud Tasks Queue from a firebase function that calls when an entry in a firebase Realtime Database is created. However when the function is supposed to create the task it throws the following Error:

```
Error: 3 INVALID_ARGUMENT: Task.payload_type is not set.
at Object.callErrorFromStatus (D:\programming\AndroidStudioProjects\TWILY\firebaseBackend\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call.js:31:26)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\programming\AndroidStudioProjects\TWILY\firebaseBackend\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client.js:180:52)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\programming\AndroidStudioProjects\TWILY\firebaseBackend\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:336:141)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (D:\programming\AndroidStudioProjects\TWILY\firebaseBackend\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\client-interceptors.js:299:181)
at D:\programming\AndroidStudioProjects\TWILY\firebaseBackend\functions\node_modules\@grpc\grpc-js\build\src\call-stream.js:160:78
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:77:11)
```

The relevant code is as follows:

```
const project = JSON.parse(process.env.FIREBASE_CONFIG).projectId;
const location = "europe-west1";
const queue = "message-queue";

const tasksClient = new CloudTasksClient();
const queuePath = tasksClient.queuePath(project, location, queue);
console.log(queuePath);

const url = `https://${location}-${project}.cloudfunctions.net/sendMessageCallback`;

const task = {
  httpRequest: {
    httpMethod: "POST",
    url: url,
    body: Buffer.from("Hello there").toString("base64"),
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    },
  },
  scheduleTime: {
    seconds: scheduleSendSeconds,
  },
};

const taskRequest = {parent: queuePath};
taskRequest["task-" + scheduleSendMillis.toString()] = task;
console.log(taskRequest);

return tasksClient.createTask(taskRequest);
```

I have not been able to find out anything about the supposedly required Task.payload_type field.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I am posting an answer as this will not format well as a comment.

Is there a reason you are modifying the task key name:

```
const taskRequest = {parent: queuePath};
taskRequest["task-" + scheduleSendMillis.toString()] = task;
```

Instead of doing this:

```
const taskRequest = {parent: parent, task: task};
```

I belive that is the source of the error related to **Task.payload_type**

Comment: The reason is that in a queue task names need to be unique. The task name can only be used again 10 days after the task's completion. That's why I'm using a timestamp to name my tasks.

Comment: @OwlSurojit Are you sure you can rename in that manner? If you want to name the task use **task.name = 'my-new-name'** Link to the documentation: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.queues.tasks#Task Also note this detail **The user can optionally specify a task name. If a name is not specified then the system will generate a random unique task id** I have not verified your code by executing it, but I don't think that is the correct technique and is causing the error.